# UIActivityViewController unable to set subject when sharing to Gmail app

Tags: ios, ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller

I see via sharing content from other apps that it is possible to set a different subject and body when using share sheet to share into the Gmail Mail app.  I have implemented it and it works fine on the native mail app but not Gmail.

Going into Yelp and sharing a business then choosing gmail from the share sheet, I see that the subject and body are different.  The subject contains the address of the business while the body contains the address + a link to the business on Yelp.

I have tried to replicate this logic with success on the native Mail app but not in the Gmail app.

I have tried the following:

**Implementing UIActivityItemSource methods**

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self] applicationActivities:nil];

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return @"";
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {   
    return @"body";
}

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    return @"subject";
}
```

**Result**

Apple Mail Subject set to "subject", Body set to "body"

Gmail Subject set to "body", Body set to "body"

```
- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
```

Is never called when sharing into the Gmail app.

**I then try the more hack way of doing it**

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"body"] applicationActivities:nil];
[activityViewController setValue:@"subject" forKey:@"subject"];
```

**Result**

Apple Mail Subject set to "subject", Body set to "body"

Gmail Subject set to "body", Body set to "body"

**Any way to make Gmail Behave like Apple Mail?**

Again, I have seen that other applications like Yelp and Safari have gotten the proper behavior out of the Gmail app through share sheet.  Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like Gmail just pulls from the body up until the first blank line and makes that the subject

Comment: @dan Do you have a test string I can try?  I tried @"This is the first part.\n\nThis is the second part." but still the same behavior.

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for that? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Also stuck here... Any solution? thanks

Comment: I was not able to find a solution to this.

Comment: Issue is happening with React Native too. Gmail decides to just take the body and put it in the subject.

Comment: Any solution to this yet? Can someone love this post

Comment: Is there a solution on this?

Comment: I can't find a solution either this issue is driving me nuts

Answer (score -3):

`[_activityViewController setValue:subject forKey:@"subject"];`-Not supported way.

Correct way to set body and subject (iOS 7.0 and later) 
- implement `UIActivityItemSource` protocol on item to share.

```
//  EmailDataProvider.h

@interface EmailItemProvider : NSObject <UIActivityItemSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *body;

@end


//  EmailDataProvider.m

    @implementation EmailDataProvider

- (id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController {
    return _body;
}

- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    return _body;
}

- (NSString *)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController subjectForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType {
    return _subject;
}

@end
```

And than present it:

```
EmailDataProvider *emailItem = [[EmailDataProvider alloc]init];

emailItem.subject = @"This is Subject text.";

emailItem.body = @"This is Body,set by programatically";

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[emailItem]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: In my question, I post that I already tried the UIActivityItemSource protocol and it was not working for the gmail app, working for the native mail app only.  Did you try the implementation yourself while sharing with the Gmail app?

Comment: Latest Outlook Appin downloaded iOS 11 sets subject and body as empty.